# Making a sort of "tags" list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to make in Angular, a list where you could select multiple items, and that these items would appear in a field near the select, and that you could delete them at will; like the "tags" field when you ask a question here.

So far, i did this :

```
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <p>{{classesSelected}}</p>
            <md-select ng-model="classesSelected" multiples>
                <md-option ng-value="classe.name" ng-repeat="classe in vm.classes">
                    {{classe.name}}                        
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

It gives me this : 
[image: the list]
here, you can see the list working like i'd want it to
[image: the element with my choice]
and here the field with the data selected

i'd like that selecting an element would remove it from the list (or make it impossible to pick it again) and create a "block" in the field, with its name a little cross or something to remove it if i want to.
Picking another element from the list would ADD it to the field, and not reset it.

I have no idea how to do it, like i see the logic but i don't know how to realize it in Angular. Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution might be to use two lists :

- One list with the item the user can select
- One list with the items the user selected

I'm not sure about what you want,
but here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtemisYoung/sjLrLhp2/2/)

```
function MyCtrl() {
  this.options = ['Maternelle', 'CP', 'CE1', 'CM1'];//Possible to select
  this.selected = [];//Chosen by user

}

MyCtrl.prototype.change = function(value) {//Called when the user select an option
  if (value && value.length) {
    this.selected.push(value);
    this.options = this.options.filter(x => x != value);
  }
}


MyCtrl.prototype.removeSelection = function(value) {//Called when the user click on the little cross
  if (value && value.length) {
    this.options.push(value);
    this.selected = this.selected.filter(x => x != value);
  }
}
```

Comment: your jsfiddle is broken... but i understood my question was unclear ? can i add anything ?

Comment: oh well it works, let me try to make it work with my solution